# XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1

Tags: asp.net-core

whenever I am trying to execute this view page I am getting the exception

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="border p-3">

        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pl-3">Add Category</h2>
            <h2 class="text-info pl-3">Add Category</h2>
      
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In other views,will you get the same error?And what you did before you got this error?

Comment: If I remove asp-action then my view is working but I have to store data in database